# React call function from useState , like useState(func())

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Dumb question,
can I call/invoke function inside useState?
I mean `useState(myfunc())` or should I do `const func = myfunc()`, then `useState(func)` or it doesnt matter at all? and there are no side effects of doing this? 
I would like to know good/best practices in this area. The general approach is to save in state value that function returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can:**

Sometimes it's good to have a common function that is being used in several components and so that you can import it and use as you are asking, which has synchronous execution and returning values.

---

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const getNames = () => {
    return ["Vivek" , "Darhista" , "Darshvi"]
  }

  const [users,setUsers] = useState(getNames());


  return (
    <div>
      { users.map(user => <p>{user}</p>) }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) (I will mark it as solution in few mins cause, seems there is some kind of anti bot system thus it says 9min )

Comment: @krissXawera, sure no issue, glad to know it helped